# Are there plans to support the TikZ frontend for l3draw?

Tags: tikz-pgf, l3draw

In is current stage, `l3draw` is rather cumbersome to use. The same applies to `pgf`. Since both are background layers, I guess there are not really meant to be used extensively by regular users.

Are there plans to support TikZ as a frontend for `l3draw`?

This would have quite a few advantages for the end user, such as better numerical precision. I don't think that a new frontend would be a good idea, since TikZ has a vast user base and there are so many useful libraries.

Comment: At this point `l3draw` has not even reached feature parity with PGF. Things like patterns, shadings and fadings are not implemented at all I believe.

Comment: @HenriMenke Indeed: they all need PDF manangement

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer: no.

One of the core aims of work on `expl3` is to provide a way of programming LaTeX that does not rely on the mix of TeX primitives, internal LaTeX macros and documents programmer/designer/document commands that are seen in 'classical' LaTeX2e packages. Much of that is about provided the core programming layer, but extends to other areas that otherwise need primitive support.

Creating drawings using PDF/PostScript/SVG/... constructs at the most basic level is carried out using one or more primitives: `\special`, `\pdfliteral`, etc. Those clearly fall into 'TeX primitive' layer. What `l3draw` aims to do is abstract sufficiently that basic drawing constructs can be created using documented `expl3` interfaces. The work started when the team were still imagining a future LaTeX format independent of LaTeX2e, but the central idea remains applicable now that this goal has been moved away from.

As such, `l3draw` could be used to implement various higher-level interfaces: for example, one can relatively easily make something that looks like picture mode. However, there are a couple of important considerations for anything TikZ-like

- Whilst `l3fp` is relatively fast for what it achieves, the `dim`-based
  approach in `pgf` is faster, particularly when skipping parsing and doing
  low-level calculations: this would be significant for a full-scale
  `l3draw`-based TikZ approach
- The TikZ interfaces are very much non-standard for LaTeX: as such, any
  code from the team is never likely to work the same way as TikZ
- Whilst `pgf` and `l3draw` do have a similar API, the dimension calculations
  in `l3draw` are done by expansion, whereas in `pgf` they are non-expandable
  and set the (documented) return `dim` registers `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y`.
  TikZ is implemented not strictly using just the `pgf` documented macro
  interfaces but also using those registers and other lower-level code. As
  such, one cannot 'drop in' `l3draw` functions to replace `pgf` ones.
- `l3draw` does not (yet) cover all of `pgf`'s functionality. There are some
  areas awaiting the outcomes of work on PDF structures (such as support for
  masks). There are also `pgf`-level ideas that one can argue do not directly
  need kernel-level `expl3` support, most notably nodes.

As such, `l3draw` is best seen as a way for package authors to build functionality using a code-level interface in packages already using `expl3`. At some stage we may load `l3draw` as part of `l3kernel`, but there is no pressure to do that at the moment.